# Left-factoring a non-left-recursive grammar to make it LL(1)

Tags: grammar

I have removed left-recursion from a left-recursive grammar given to me. The original grammar is as follows:

SPRIME::= Expr **eof**
Expr::= Term | Expr **+** Term | Expr **-** Term
Term::= Factor | Term ***** Factor | Term **/** Factor | Term **mod** Factor | Term **div** factor
Factor::= **id** | { Expr } | **num** | Funcall |
Funcall::= **id** [ Arglist ]
Arglist::= Expr | Expr , Arglist

When removing left-recursion, this is the grammar I produced:

SPRIME::= Expr **eof**
Expr::= Term Expr'
Expr'::= **e** | + Term Expr' | - Term Expr'
Term::= Factor Term'
Term'::= **e** | ***** Factor Term' | **/** Factor Term' | **mod** Factor Term' | **div** Factor Term'
Factor::= **id** |  { Expr } | **num** | Funcall
Funcall::= **id** **[** Arglist **]**
Arglist::= Expr Arglist'
Arglist'::= **,** Arglist | **e**

My next task is to perform left-factoring on this grammar in order to make it LL(1). Having read the relevant chapter in the Dragon book, I'm unsure if I need to do anything to this grammar. My question is: is this grammar in LL(1) form already? And if not, where do I need to perform left-factoring in order to make it LL(1)?

EDIT: After taking @suddnely_me's answer into account, I have edited the Arglist non-terminal in order to left-factor it's productions. Is the grammar I have now an LL(1) grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this grammar is not LL(1). At least, the last rules group is not left factored, since FIRST( Expr) and FIRST( Expr, Arglist) do interstect.

Comment: So would modifying the grammar in the following fashion transform it to LL(1)?

Comment: At first glance, yes. As I remember from my academic years, the best way to check if the grammar is LL(1) is to build LL(1) analyzer of it. There are common algorythms to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
                     if it is in the form of     A->A.ALPHA|BETA 
                        REMOVING LEFT RECURSION     A->BETA A'|
                       A'->ALPHA A'|NULL          
                       EXAMPLE:::A->A+B|a
                       IN THIS A=A A'=A'
                        ALPHA=+B
                        BETA=a
                    REMOVING LEFT RECURSION  :   A=aA'
                        A'=+BA'|NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

No, still (even a year later!) not LL(1). My oracle says:

```
Can't choose between two rules of 'Factor'
    -> id
    -> Funcall

'Funcall' can start with id.  For example:
    Funcall -> id ...
```